# emacs dired regexp mark files beginning with

Tags: regular-expression, emacs

In Emacs Dired mode, I'd like to mark directories and files whose names begin with `Addr` but **not** files that contain `Addr` inside the name. I'm using RE-Builder to test my regular expressions and am having no luck with the carat (`^`) character. I know it can mean beginning-of-line or else it can mean not.

I ultimately would like to use `%g` in Dired mode but am using RE-Builder because it lets me see what my regular expression does. The `rx` macro is beyond me right now.

`^Addr.*` does not do what I want. The `^` character apparently means not rather than beginning-of-line. `Addr.*` also finds names like `blahAddrblah`, which is not what I want.

What's the regexp trick that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^Addr` does match `Addr` at the beginning of a line. The character `^` only means “not” when it's at the beginning of a [character class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes), e.g. `[^abc]` means “any one character that isn't `a`, `b` or `c`”.

I think your problem is that you're using the command `%g`, which matches files by their content, but you meant to use `%m`, which matches files by their name. `%m ^Addr RET` marks files whose name begins with `Addr`.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right re: %m instead of %g. Thanks! I guess %g sort of means: grep reg-exp *, where * means all files in the current dired buffer. I'll have to read up more on re-builder since "^Addr" shows no results when using it, while I have several files whose names start with Addr.